# FeathersJS REST return records with specific value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I have a MySQL database with a table named 'posts' I'm reading from via [FeathersJS](https://docs.feathersjs.com/) and [feathers-sequelize](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize). Currently I have a working prototype with the following code which returns the desired result but only to the console, and also the entire contents of the posts table to the /posts route, however I only want to return a specific set of records from the table to /posts.

The table has a column called post_status, in which a post could be 'published' or 'draft'. I only want to return the 'published' records to /posts, but want to achieve this serverside as opposed to /posts?status=published. How can this be achieved?

See below code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const service = require('feathers-sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sandbox', 'sandbox', 'secretpassword', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  operatorsAliases: false
});

const Post = sequelize.define('posts', {
  post_title: Sequelize.STRING
},
{
  timestamps: false,
  underscored: true,
});

// Create an Express compatible Feathers application instance.
const app = express(feathers());

// Turn on JSON parser for REST services
app.use(express.json());
// Turn on URL-encoded parser for REST services
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Enable REST services
app.configure(express.rest());
// Enable Socket.io services
app.configure(socketio());


app.use(express.errorHandler());

//This works fine to return to the console but not to /posts
Post.findAll({
where: {
  post_status: 'published'
}
}) .then(posts => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(posts));
  });

//This returns the entire contents of the posts table to /posts
app.use('/posts', service({
  Model: Post,
  paginate: {
    default: 10,
    max: 100
  },
}));

// Start the server
const port = 3030;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Feathers server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I tried the 'where' from the findAll method in the service but this did not change the output, or produce any error.

Comment: You are not defining `post_status` in your model. It will probably work if you do (you may also want to synchronize the table with the model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using a where clause in the find method on the service, see below complete code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const service = require('feathers-sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sandbox', 'sandbox', 'secretpassword', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  operatorsAliases: false
});

const Post = sequelize.define('posts', {
  post_title: Sequelize.STRING,
  post_status: Sequelize.STRING
  
},
{
  timestamps: false,
  underscored: true,
});

// Create an Express compatible Feathers application instance.
const app = express(feathers());

// Turn on JSON parser for REST services
app.use(express.json());
// Turn on URL-encoded parser for REST services
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Enable REST services
app.configure(express.rest());
// Enable Socket.io services
app.configure(socketio());


app.use(express.errorHandler());


const myService = {
  find(params) {
    let posts = Post.findAll({
      where: {
        post_status: 'published'
      }
    });

    return Promise.resolve(posts);
  },
  get(id, params) {},
  create(data, params) {},
  update(id, data, params) {},
  patch(id, data, params) {},
  remove(id, params) {},
  setup(app, path) {}
}

app.use('/posts', myService);

// Start the server
const port = 3030;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Feathers server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```